# Internet Explorer 9: do not track: enable and disable

Tags: internet-explorer-9, tracking

I tried googling for a how-to on how to enable and disable "do not track" in Internet Explorer 9 but could not find anything. I could only find "press releases".

Please let me know the step-by-step process for how to enable and disable "do not track" in Internet Explorer 9.

I will then verify the results using the "fiddler http protocol analyzer".

NOTE: In Firefox 4, it is easy to enable and disable "do not track": http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/how-do-i-stop-websites-tracking-me?s=do+not+track&as=s

Comment: I found how to do it:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-to-use-Tracking-Protection-and-ActiveX-Filtering

Click the Tools button, point to Safety, and then click Tracking protection.

In the Manage Add-on dialog box, click a Tracking Protection list, and then click Enable (or Disable).

Comment: NOTE: (I am a nube). I found superuser after posting to serverfault and was thinking that superuser might be the better place to post. However, the question was answered at serverfault first: see: http://serverfault.com/questions/262431/ie9-do-not-track-enable-and-disable